# Why does openfiledialog say 'Path does not exist' or 'Catastrophic Error' after selecting a file for the second time?

Tags: c#, wpf, file, openfiledialog

I am trying to make a file display. When the user selects a file, it displays the icon of the file in the window. When I select the Google Chrome icon and click on 'OK' in the `openfiledialog`, the intended result happens. (see pictures below)

[image]

[image]

However, when I select another icon (e.g Word), it gives me the error 'Path does not exist'.
(see pictures below)

[image]

[image]

If I select another file (e.g File Explorer) it gives me 'Catastrophic Error' (see pictures below)

[image]

[image]

For some reason, this problem only happens with shortcut files. For other files like .txt files or .exe files, this problem does not occur.

Here is my code (Add_Item is the name of the button)

```
private void AddItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                foreach (String myfile in openFileDialog.FileNames)
                {
                    // here myfile represent your selected file name

                    //get filename
                    string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(myfile);

                    //TODO: Create settings


                    Icon icon1 =  System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(myfile);
                    Bitmap icon = icon1.ToBitmap();

                    System.Windows.Controls.Image image = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
                    image.Source = BitmapToImageSource(icon);

                    Tiles.Children.Add(image);



                }
            }
        }
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: The first time you use OpenFileDialog the default folder is null.  So before ShowDialog you need following (or equivalent) :  openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";

Comment: These are pretty unspecific errors.  You might have better luck with Project > Properties > Build tab, untick "Prefer 32-bit".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, `{DeferenceLinks = false}` fixed my problem.